WSUS April Microsoft Downloads Stuck
April Updates from Microsoft are giving me a hard time this month. I have 5 updates that download partially and then stop. These are the updates that are stuck.

If I stop all these files and do one at a time they all get to about 80% and stop. As show here:

Checking the BITS log it shows many queued but a few show up as “error processing file”. See the log below:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-BitsTransfer -AllUsers | Select *

JobId                    : 24a03748-859e-4d9e-b7de-7f83b3fac8e9
DisplayName              : Edge Component Updater
Description              : 1088e6b8-ebbd-45b2-9b3c-394b4143557c
HttpMethod               : GET
Dynamic                  : False
TransferType             : Download
JobState                 : Error
TransferPolicy           : BelowCap, UsageBased, PolicyUnrestricted
ACLFlags                 : None
SecurityFlags            : RedirectPolicyAllowSilent
NotifyFlags              : JobTransferred, JobError
OwnerAccount             : DOMAIN\Manager
Priority                 : Normal
RetryInterval            : 60
RetryTimeout             : 86400
MaxDownloadTime          : 7776000
TransientErrorCount      : 251
ProxyUsage               : SystemDefault
ErrorContext             : RemoteFile
ErrorCondition           :
InternalErrorCode        : -2147012894
ErrorDescription         : The operation timed out

ErrorContextDescription  : The error occurred while the remote file was being processed.

BytesTotal               : 18446744073709551615
BytesTransferred         : 0
FilesTotal               : 1
FilesTransferred         : 0
CreationTime             : 4/15/2024 12:27:53 PM
ModificationTime         : 4/16/2024 3:57:27 PM
TransferCompletionTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
FileList                 : {http://msedge.b.tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/1088e6b8-ebbd-4
                           5b2-9b3c-394b4143557c?P1=1713335366&P2=404&P3=2&P4=TFxqBC8WtMeSCGT6oN9Aq%2fnXW%2fTzm4XDlPYYL
                           dftOFb8JxaPLTXqUljOj6yIbn4XEOU9aUgDs7v7DXCMBLb6kA%3d%3d}
ProxyList                :
ProxyBypassList          :
NotifyCmdLine            : {, }
CustomHeaders            :
CertificateStoreLocation : CurrentUser
CertificateStoreName     :
CertificateHash          :
CertificateSubjectName   :

JobId                    : f5dfd99a-9e8b-4502-8177-95eaf0c37b01
DisplayName              : C:\Users\Manager\AppData\Local\Temp\{BA3E3051-E8EB-4901-A93C-0D227FCF308B}-MicrosoftEdgeUpd
                           ateSetup_X86_1.3.185.29.exe
Description              : Microsoft Edge Update
HttpMethod               : GET
Dynamic                  : False
TransferType             : Download
JobState                 : Queued
TransferPolicy           : BelowCap, UsageBased, PolicyUnrestricted
ACLFlags                 : None
SecurityFlags            : RedirectPolicyAllowReport
NotifyFlags              : 11
OwnerAccount             : DOMAIN\Manager
Priority                 : Normal
RetryInterval            : 60
RetryTimeout             : 0
MaxDownloadTime          : 7776000
TransientErrorCount      : 0
ProxyUsage               : NoProxy
ErrorContext             : None
ErrorCondition           : NoError
InternalErrorCode        : 0
ErrorDescription         :
ErrorContextDescription  :
BytesTotal               : 18446744073709551615
BytesTransferred         : 0
FilesTotal               : 1
FilesTransferred         : 0
CreationTime             : 4/16/2024 5:50:42 PM
ModificationTime         : 4/17/2024 12:04:12 AM
TransferCompletionTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
FileList                 : {http://msedge.b.tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/72ed8087-ee98-4
                           29c-9330-ca3c193d41af?P1=1713908137&P2=404&P3=2&P4=WwvWtR2QwN4wVUQSyq%2b1GrCrGg4ohhfvhmvKloe
                           4Vnp0zfbh5v0DTcUOqUah1wY5YTJtmiACu%2bNfcHdkLg5pVA%3d%3d}
ProxyList                :
ProxyBypassList          :
NotifyCmdLine            : {, }
CustomHeaders            : {X-Last-HR:, 0x80040893, , X-Last-HTTP-Status-Code:...}
CertificateStoreLocation : CurrentUser
CertificateStoreName     :
CertificateHash          :
CertificateSubjectName   :

JobId                    : 49682fe7-8c27-4acb-8a8a-1de32bcef56e
DisplayName              : fe92b167-ad99-4551-82a1-59b8a6c302d3
Description              : SUSFile
HttpMethod               : GET
Dynamic                  : False
TransferType             : Download
JobState                 : Connecting
TransferPolicy           : NoSurcharge
ACLFlags                 : None
SecurityFlags            : RedirectPolicyAllowSilent
NotifyFlags              : JobTransferred, JobError
OwnerAccount             : NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Priority                 : High
RetryInterval            : 600
RetryTimeout             : 86400
MaxDownloadTime          : 7776000
TransientErrorCount      : 0
ProxyUsage               : NoProxy
ErrorContext             : None
ErrorCondition           : NoError
InternalErrorCode        : 0
ErrorDescription         :
ErrorContextDescription  :
BytesTotal               : 6740860756
BytesTransferred         : 5998116273
FilesTotal               : 1
FilesTransferred         : 0
CreationTime             : 4/17/2024 12:04:12 AM
ModificationTime         : 4/17/2024 6:54:14 AM
TransferCompletionTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
FileList                 : {http://dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/12e61594-4322-476a-a334-2dc8
                           ffd0ba2c/public/featureondemand_7417219a2a60c9cb6a90160ad120e6bd7054bd65.wim}
ProxyList                :
ProxyBypassList          :
NotifyCmdLine            : {, }
CustomHeaders            :
CertificateStoreLocation : CurrentUser
CertificateStoreName     :
CertificateHash          :
CertificateSubjectName   :

JobId                    : 7f9e5f84-953d-4f78-8255-164a176f9d1a
DisplayName              : 04a546ec-6f3d-40d2-8e5e-9a5530300b39
Description              : SUSFile
HttpMethod               : GET
Dynamic                  : False
TransferType             : Download
JobState                 : Queued
TransferPolicy           : NoSurcharge
ACLFlags                 : None
SecurityFlags            : RedirectPolicyAllowSilent
NotifyFlags              : JobTransferred, JobError
OwnerAccount             : NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Priority                 : High
RetryInterval            : 600
RetryTimeout             : 86400
MaxDownloadTime          : 7776000
TransientErrorCount      : 0
ProxyUsage               : NoProxy
ErrorContext             : None
ErrorCondition           : NoError
InternalErrorCode        : 0
ErrorDescription         :
ErrorContextDescription  :
BytesTotal               : 6026932616
BytesTransferred         : 5297126593
FilesTotal               : 1
FilesTransferred         : 0
CreationTime             : 4/17/2024 12:04:12 AM
ModificationTime         : 4/17/2024 6:54:14 AM
TransferCompletionTime   : 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
FileList                 : {http://dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/8a3ac009-3385-411e-833e-212c
                           9b6f86d3/public/featureondemand_3294af9937b733783476da837b21943dc160faaa.wim}
ProxyList                :
ProxyBypassList          :
NotifyCmdLine            : {, }
CustomHeaders            :
CertificateStoreLocation : CurrentUser
CertificateStoreName     :
CertificateHash          :
CertificateSubjectName   :

This has been like this for a week now since release from Microsoft. WSUS Server is running Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard.
I have tried clearly the WSUS Content and resetting WSUS to redownload the files. It gets to these 5 and then stops. I have also used AJTek’s WSUS Clean up script so it is not that the database is filled with crap.
Has anyone seen this and have they figured it out? Are you having any issues downloading files from MIcrosoft Server for WSUS?
